# Function luego de ...MapState[] / VUEX

Tags: vue.js, vuex

sencillo. Tengo este metodo.

```
  methods: {
...mapActions(["getConfig"])
}
```

Lo llamo desde aca

```
<v-btn @click="getConfig">Mostrar</v-btn>
```

Trae datos de la .store, funciona ok. Yo quiero cambiar un dato primero y luego de ejecutar     ...mapActions(["getConfig"])

Ejemplo:

```
methods: {
this.valor = 0
...mapActions(["getConfig"])
this.valor = 1
}
```

Obviamente esto va a dar error, alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crear otra función que haga lo que quieres y a la vez llame a la función del `store`:

```
methods: {
    getLocalConfig: function() {
        this.valor = 0
        this.getConfig()
        this.valor = 1
    },
    ...mapActions(["getConfig"])
}
```

```
<v-btn @click="getLocalConfig">Mostrar</v-btn>
```